# I need to execute the login script multiple times

Tags: automation, cypress

I started script writing and there are 5 pages
01.Sign in
02.Login
03.Dasboard
04.Account Page
05.Settings Page

I wrote seperate test cases for all pages. Written test cases for login page is successfully completed.Then when I try to execute script for dasboard page.There are 5 test cases have to verify.In that case I user beforeEach method for call the login script and use 5 it blocks for those 5 test cases. The issue is I need to login again and again to run that 5 cases. I need to run all 5 test cases with one login.

```js
require('@cypress/xpath')
import '../../support/commands'

import {searchPage} from '../../PageObjects/Serach&FilterPage.js';


const SandF = new searchPage()

describe('Login', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login('username', 'password');
        cy.wait(1000); 
      });

      it('Search functionality with name', () => {

        cy.xpath("//p[contains(.,'Candidates')]").should('have.text','Candidates')
        cy.wait(2000);
          })

      it('Filter functionality with By Completion Status ', () => {
        SandF.Status().click({ force: true })
        cy.wait(5000); 
        cy.contains('Pending').focused().click({ force: true })
        cy.wait(1500); 
     
            })

      it('Filter functionality with By Completion Status =', () => {
      
       SandF.Status().click({ force: true })
        cy.wait(2000); 
        cy.contains('Passed & Completed').scrollIntoView().click({ force: true })
       
            })

      it('Filter functionality with By Completion Status', () => { 
        SandF.Status().click({ force: true })
        cy.wait(1000); 
        cy.contains('Failed & Completed').scrollIntoView().click({ force: true })
        SandF.Reset().click({ force: true })
    })`
    })`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `beforeEach()` to use a `cy.session()`, so that it only logs in once but keeps the credentials each test

```js
describe('A suite of tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session('login', () => {
      cy.login('username', 'password');
    })
  })

  it('test1 will be logged in', () => {...

  it('test2 will be logged in', () => {...
})
```

Read more about it in the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)